# Working version of Android App not installing after downloading corrupted version

Tags: android

I installed a corrupted version of my android app on my phone and it did not work. I uninstalled it fixed the issue and then the app would still not launch but would launch in my emulator. I tried installing the app on the same model android device but another phone and the app ran flawlessly on it. I have tried clearing the cache and data of the app but to no avail. Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the error message? Include it in the post. The more details you add (erros logs, screenshots, etc)  the more chances you get proper help.

Comment: How do I get the error logs?

Comment: You can check logcat output at Android Studio. Briefly: Connect your device enabling USB debugging. Open Android Studio,  select Logcat tab at the bottom tabs and choose the device at the top left combo box in the Logcat window.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for the APK file on your Android device. Uninstalling the app doesn't delete the APK file. Sometimes the installer gets confused if there is an old APK file lying around. It's usually in the Internal storage > Downloads folder, but it may have been stashed somewhere else. If you find an old APK, delete it, and then try installing your app again.